# Running high powered/current LEDs with high frequency

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

firstly i would want to thank all who are willing to help me in this problem that i am facing.

So to begin, i am a high school student doing a final year project. Basically i have to create a circuit where by a 1000Hz frequency is an input that i have to alternate it so that my output will be toggling with half of the input frequency.
Therefore i am using a single J-K Flip Flop which has a Q & Q(bar) output. That i do not have a problem....

However the problem comes in here. from the 2 outputs of my J-K Flip Flop, i have to use each output to power up 20 LEDs in series, which has to be 1.7V each LED and 700mA, making it 34V with 700mA.

But the output of a J-K Flip Flop does not produce enough voltage and current.

i have tried using a BuckPuck after the output, and realise the rise and fall time is too slow for the high frequency.

i found out that a NPN Transistir ( BD137 ) has a very fast Rise and Fall time, however after configuring the circuit, the output measure was 34v But only 200mA....

please help me to get a 34V and 700mA, thank you.

Comment: How have you connected the NPN? What's the resistor on the base of it? What load is the NPN driving when you get that 34V, 200mA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to use the signal to turn on a FET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Vzy4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The FET needs to have a threshold voltage (V<sub>gs</sub>) well below the output of the J/K, ideally in the 2-3 V region if it's a 5 V flip flop. You also want the on resistance (R<sub>ds</sub> on) to be low enough that the power consumption at 700mA isn't an issue (power = I<sup>2</sup>*R). The maximum on current (I<sub>d</sub> MAX) should also be well over 700mA. Finally the maximum allowed drain-source voltage must be over 34V.

Comment: To add to Andrew's response, look for a logic level, N channel FET.

Comment: To add more: depending on exactly what logic voltage you are using, look for a FET which is specifically called a "logic-level" FET.

Comment: @Andrew is it possible to set it up without any resistor?

Comment: @AmosLimJY That depends on your LEDs and power supply, you need something to limit the current draw. If the LEDs or supply already limit the current to the correct level then the resistor isn't needed. If they are just LEDs on their own and a standard constant voltage power supply then you need to limit the current in some way or things will go pop. A resistor is the simplest way to do this. If using a constant current power supply make sure that the FET is OK with the maximum voltage the supply outputs.